# Finding the maximum expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

Say we have $a_1, a_2, ..., a_m \in \{0, 1\}^n$ where the sum over the elements of each vector $a_i$ is $k$.

Let $b \in \{0, 1\}^n$ be a random vector based on the uniform distribution.

Also, let $c_i = a_i^T \cdot b$, which is a scalar value.

$E[c_i] = (1/2) * k = k/2$, since the probability that $b$ has 
an element '1' at the same index as $a_i$ is (1/2).

However, what is $E[\max_i c_i]$ ? or the highest expected scalar value over all $c_i$  values for $i=\{1,2,...,m\}$.

Clearly, $E[\max_i c_i]$ should be closer to $k$ and should be a function of $m$.

Comment: Actually $E(c_i)=k/2$.

Comment: @Did, I see, is it because there is only one random vector ? so the probability that it has a '1' at the same index as '$a_i$' is (1/2).

Comment: This depends on the $a_i$. If the $a_i$ happen to be identical, the maximum expected value would be $k/2$. Are we taking the average over all possible $m$-tuples of $n$-tuples?